# Sophie Germain and the outlook on science

Tags: mathematics

I have two questions.

1. What is the importance of Sophie Germain's work with Fermat's last theorem, if her only contribution was Sophie Germain prime numbers? Euler was able to calculate on the problem before, right?
2. What was the general outlook on science during Sophie's lifetime (including the French Revolution)?

Comment: 1) for information on the lives and works of mathematicians (including Sophie Germain) see http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/~history/BiogIndex.html